# Pyspark - Sample without replacement

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

As I noticed, I have a very unbalanced variable. So, I want to sample it by giving weights to each class of my variable. This is my dataset (dd):

```
l = [('Alice', 1),('Alice', 1),('Alice', 1),('Alice', 1),('Alice', 1),('Alice',1),('Mary', 1),('Alice', 1),('Alice', 1),('Mary', 1)]
dd == spark.createDataFrame(l)

dd.show()
+-----+------+
| Name| Label|
+-----+------+
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
| Mary|     1|
|Alice|     1|
|Alice|     1|
| Mary|     1|
+-----+------+
```

I want Alice and Mary to have the same percentage on my dataset.I used this :

```
  sampledDf = dd.sampleBy("_1", fractions={"Alice":0.5, "Mary":0.5}, seed=1234)
```

and I got no error. But, when I try to see the sampledDf (sampledDf.show()), my command is not running.

Which is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you are hoping for:

```
+-----+---+
|   _1| _2|
+-----+---+
|Alice|  1|
|Alice|  1|
| Mary|  1|
|Alice|  1|
| Mary|  1|
+-----+---+
```

Can you provide desired output?

Also check if the command is running in background or crashed

Comment: Yes, this is the desirable result.

Comment: Well i didn't see any problem
Did a simple word count program works on your spark installation?